# Sketch Plugin : Fetch GET request, security settings

Tags: javascript

I am trying to develop a sketch plugin, I use the official SKPM to build a simple request, through Fetch, but I got a security error: Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1022

My code is as follows:

```
fetch('http://www.baidu.com')
.then(function(response) {
return response.json();
})
.then(function(myJson) {
console.log(myJson);
});
```

When I tried to change the requested connection from http to https, everything worked fine.

The complete error message is as follows:

```
Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1022 "The resource could not be loaded because the App Transport Security policy requires the use of a secure connection." UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x6000071e9260 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1022 "The resource could not be loaded because the App Transport Security policy requires the use of a secure connection." UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://www.baidu.com/, NSLocalizedDescription=The resource could not be loaded because the App Transport Security policy requires the use of a secure connection., NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://www.baidu.com/}}, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://www.baidu.com/, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://www.baidu.com/, NSLocalizedDescription=The resource could not be loaded because the App Transport Security policy requires the use of a secure connection.}
>
```

I want to know how to set up so that Fetch's request can support http connection? Because I am in a development environment, there is no server that supports https.

Comment: What was the error? Add `.catch(err => { console.error(err) })`

Comment: <NSURLError> Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1022 "The resource could not be loaded because the App Transport Security policy requires the use of a secure connection."